# add hidden field to wordpress registeration

Tags: php, wordpress

i am creating a website using wordpress, i am trying to assign an 11 eleven character based code to everyone who registers on my website.

I intend to use a an hidden field on the wordpress registeration page to to generate the code using this

```
<?php echo mt_rand(10000, 99999);?><?php echo mt_rand(10000, 99999);?>
```

, pass it to the database and also send this code as an email.

i have no idea on how to go about this, can some one please advice on how i can achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have any hidden field just generate a random coupon code after user registration hook and save in user meta and email as below

In you functions.php file

```
add_action('user_register','create_coupon_code',10,1);
function create_coupon_code($user_id ){
    $coupon_code = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    //Now save this number to database in usermeta field as below
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'coupon', $coupon_code, false );

    // now use php mail or whatever you want for email to send the generated coupon $coupon_code;
    }
```

Comment: wow cool, but as far as i know wordpress has its own email poece of snippet